# Getting Error "cannot use immediate apply method for static parameter"

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, boto

While modifying parameter "`lower_case_table_names = 1`" of `rds` using `boto`, I am getting this error:

> cannot use immediate apply method for static parameter

Answer (score 26):

You are getting this error because the apply method is set to *immediate* and this parameter can only be changed on a reboot.

Change the apply method to `pending-reboot`.

See the [documentation on modifying db parameters](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/APIReference/API_ModifyDBParameterGroup.html) and the [documentation for parameters](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/APIReference/API_Parameter.html) for more information.

Comment: I am using boto for creating rds parameter group and setting their parameters. How can we apply pending-reboot method and where?

Comment: Hi I used `pending-reboot` for my AWS Aurora serverless database, but I don't see a ''reboot" button in the console, how should I reboot the cluster to make the changes in paraneter groups to take effect?